# How to make a sandbox game with java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a game that simulates chemical reactions. The problem is, after about five dust particles, the game crashes. Here's the code that moves particles:

```
public class Element extends Thread {
  long temperature;
  double x;
  double y;
  double XVel;
  double YVel = 5;
  ImageView iv;
  Duration dur;
  TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      move();// calls the movement method repeatedly
      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Element.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    }
  }

  public void initialize() {
    this.start();
  }

  /**
   * @return the temperature
   */
  public long getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
  }

  public void checkCollisions() {

  }

  public void move() {
    tt.setDuration(dur.millis(5));
    tt.setByY(YVel);
    tt.setCycleCount(1);
    tt.setNode(iv);
    tt.play();
  }
}
```

Then, this exception comes up, and the game stops working:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:366)
at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:366)
at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractMasterTimer.java:289)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:459)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:332)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I don't know why a NullPointerException occurs, can anybody help me (I'm using JavaFX)?
It would be very helpful if someone could tell me how this game does it (http://dan-ball.jp/en/javagame/dust/), for this game shows what i'm trying to accomplish. See for yourself.

Comment: Well, obviously, something didn't get initialized correctly. Can't tell what, though...

Comment: Which line? That would help us to tell you why this happened. But something is null and is being used in your code which needs to get an object that has a value.

Comment: Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the value of `dur` when you call `move()`?

Comment: I cannot see where do you initialize your `Duration` variable, therefore `dur.millis(5)` could cause the exception, but can't tell for sure from the code provided.

Comment: I dont know which line it occurs. Usually, NetBeans would tell me, but it's not.

Comment: There are numerous issues with your code as others have pointed out, study [this animated physics in JavaFX sample](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) to see how you could achieve the behaviour you want.

Comment: If it was my Duration variable, why did it work the first several times?

Comment: wait, initiallizing the Duration variable greatly improved the performance, but i still keep getting the same Exception, but after about 50 particles.

Comment: Where do you initialize `ImageView iv`? I see you use it in `tt.setNode(iv);`

Comment: When the background gets clicked, a dust class initializes iv with a fully loaded ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that TranslateTransition isn't exactly memory efficient. When I profiled my project, I notice memory spikes that don't come back down whenever a particle is placed.

> There are numerous issues with your code as others have pointed out, study this animated physics in JavaFX sample (https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) to see how you could achieve the behaviour you want. –  jewelsea Jun 17 at 19:30

This reference really helped out. I should really be able to finish my game, now.